# Wordpress Subfolder issue with Nginx Configuration

Tags: nginx, configuration, wordpress

I am using wordpress and it's a multi-site subfolder config.

```
 - www.xyz.com is pointing to /var/www/project (Working)
 - (Wordpress blog) www.xyz.com/blog is pointing to /var/www/blog (Working)
 - (Wordpress blog) www.xyz.com/blog/page/2 (not working - Error given below)
```

So if I open page www.xyz.com/blog/page/2 or www.xyz.com/blog/2015/11/15/takeup, it should point to /var/www/blog rather than pointing to /var/www/blog/page/2/index.php.

Here is my Nginx config file:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name xyz.com;
     rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
     return 301 $scheme://www.xyz.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    server_name www.xyz.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        root /var/www/project/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;


        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                expires 365d;
        }

        location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
                expires 30d;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
                gzip_vary on;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME      $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location /blog {
           alias /var/www/blog;
           if (!-e $request_filename) {
               rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
               rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
               rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
           }     
           location ~ \.php$ {  
               #try_files $uri =404;
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;                 
               #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include fastcgi_params;
          }
          rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
          rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
    }   
}
```

I am getting 404:

```
2016/01/23 23:27:05 [error] 32532#0: *2 "/var/www/blog/page/2/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 27.5.217.2, server: www.xyz.com, request: "GET /blog/page/2/ HTTP/1$
```

(Edited to improve error log formatting)

Comment: Can you please post your entire config, including URLs (example.com is fine), and describe precisely what works and what doesn't. Note that Wordpress Multisite can be either fiddly or impossible with subfolder installs, but I'm not sure that's relevant in this case - once you expand on your question someone may be able to tell. WPMU likes to own the domain, at least in subdomain mode.

Comment: @Tim Hey, updated the question. Do take a look.

Comment: This may be a silly question due to my limited nginx experience, but why are you using alias instead of root instead the blog location? I have WPMU and I use root at the server level, not the location block level. Also why is Wordpress not on the root of the domain? Are you serving something different on the domain root, with the blog in a subfolder? Note that everything service by Wordpress goes through index.php in the Wordpress root, the uri is a parameter to index.php.

Comment: I am serving another project on my root level and blog is in the subfolder but it's a different project altogether so created a new directory and accessing through www.xyz.com/blog.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is the problem is the alias you have in your blog location is a problem, plug your config looks messy. I have one site that serves random PHP on the document root and Wordpress single site in the blog folder, here's the important parts of the config I use. Note I've removed all caching and header manipulation, and I use HHVM not PHP.

I also have a WPMU site, it doesn't require anything special in the way of location block configuration. I couldn't the child blogs to be in a subfolder, that's why I have one Wordpress single site install as well.

They key is you may not need a location block for your blog, you may just need try_files in your root block with "/blog/index.php?args"

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/whatever;


  # Default location to serve
  location / {
    # If the file can't be found try adding a slash on the end - it might be
    # a directory the client is looking for. Then try the Wordpress blog URL
    # this might send a few requests to PHP that don't need to go that way
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?args;
    more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers "Expires";
  }

  # Send HipHop and PHP requests to HHVM
  location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass   php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure this will solve your problem, but it's the best I can do without doing the diagnosis myself. Even if this fails trying the ideas in this will give further information that might help solve the problem.